# Need pointers on setting field widths on my printf conversion specifications

Tags: c

This is such a basic thing, but I need pointers on how to set up the field widths so that the table prints out nice and neatly for all values allowed. I have been playing around with it for a while and am having troubles. Is there maybe some trick to quickly figure it out? Just a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
 //Print the results in a table
printf("\n#============================================#\n");
printf("| Description                 |  Input Data  |\n");
printf("|============================================|\n");
printf("| Loan amount                 | $  %8.2f  |\n", loan);
printf("| Yearly interest rate        |      %6.2f% |\n", rate);
printf("| Number of years             |       %d     |\n", years);
printf("|============================================|\n");
printf("| Payment Details             |   Results    |\n");
printf("|============================================|\n");
printf("| The monthly payment will be | $     %5.2f  |\n", monthlyPayment);
printf("| Interest paid               | $    %6.2f  |\n", interestEarned);
printf("#============================================#\n\n");
```

Comment: Change (6.2, 5.2) to 8.2, no need for 3 different ones.  Change %d to %8d

Comment: ... and `%8d` for the `int`. The first number is the total field width. (oh @chux already edited his comment)

Comment: Also that dangling `"% |\n"` --> `"%% |\n"`

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion though? I really want to know so I can do it myself in the future.

Comment: Just make every field width the size of the largest. Since the numbers are right-justified, it's ok if the field width is larger than it needs to be.  Also, note that `%8.2f` means a *total* of eight characters, including the decimal point and the two digits after the decimal point. So the largest number that fits into an `8.2` format is `99999.99`. Where I live, that doesn't even come close to buying a house, so I would use something like `%11.2f` for all the floating point numbers and `%11d` for the number of years.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting data is closer to art than science.

1. Consider that field widths will change (more likely grow) over the project's life.
2. Post code for ease of maintenance.  It is never right the first time.  Performance is not so critical as output is a sink-hole of CPU cycles anyways.
3. Re-use formats.
4. Avoid `fprintf()` of a string literal, instead use `fputs()`.
5. RTFM on `fprintf()` and let minimum width specifiers be your friend.
6. Watch out for a lone `"%"` in a format.  Should be `"%%"`

First attempt:

```
  double loan, rate,  monthlyPayment, interestEarned;
  loan = interestEarned = monthlyPayment = 12345.78;
  rate = 999.99;
  int years = 30;

  //  Let us assume interesting part of the table is 10 wide

  // 10 =
  // .max_width
  const char *fdash = "%s%.10s%s";

  // space, 8 char, space
  // - left justify
  // min_width.max_width
  const char *ftext = "%s %-8.8s %s";

  // $, 8 width with 2 dec. places, space
  // width.precision
  const char *fcash = "%s$%8.2f %s";

  // space, 7 width, %, space  
  // width.precision
  const char *fperc = "%s %7.2f%% %s";

  // space, 8 wide, space
  // width
  const char *fyear = "%s %8d %s";
  const char *bar   = "=================================="; // extra long

  fputs("\n", stdout);
  printf(fdash, "#==============================", bar           , "#\n");
  printf(ftext, "| Description                 |", "Input Data"  , "|\n");
  printf(fdash, "|==============================", bar           , "|\n");
  printf(fcash, "| Loan amount                 |", loan          , "|\n");
  printf(fperc, "| Yearly interest rate        |", rate          , "|\n");
  printf(fyear, "| Number of years             |", years         , "|\n");
  printf(fdash, "|==============================", bar           , "|\n");
  printf(ftext, "| Payment Details             |", "Results"     , "|\n");
  printf(fdash, "|==============================", bar           , "|\n");
  printf(fcash, "| The monthly payment will be |", monthlyPayment, "|\n");
  printf(fcash, "| Interest paid               |", interestEarned, "|\n");
  printf(fdash, "#==============================", bar           , "#\n");
  fputs("\n", stdout);
```

Output: Field too small for `"Input Data"`.  Fix left for user.

```
#========================================#
| Description                 | Input Da |
|========================================|
| Loan amount                 |$12345.78 |
| Yearly interest rate        |  999.99% |
| Number of years             |       30 |
|========================================|
| Payment Details             | Results  |
|========================================|
| The monthly payment will be |$12345.78 |
| Interest paid               |$12345.78 |
#========================================#
```